# How to get or retrieve or fetch id of last row or song in listview?

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I am making a Music Player application. I fetch the first 
row or song id in a listview, but I cannot fetch or retrieve last row id in the listview. 
The listview contains multiple songs and I need to get the last song id.

How can I fetch it?

Comment: How are you populating the listview?

Answer (score 0):

If u are populating data using Cursor then u can find it easily.cursor.getcount() will give the total number of records.
thn apply if condition.

```
 int records = 0; // record will contain the counter for record

for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++) {
record = i;
    if(records == cursor.getcount() {
     // this will give the last record
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define getItem() method of adapter, to returrn song item(Custom Structure or Hashmap/Hashtable), and to fetch last item from adapter, use:

```
SongItem item=adapter.getItem(adapter.count()-1);
```

and use this item to fetch id, album, etc.